# WinEvent >EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND< invocation sometimes delayed

Tags: c#, windows

For a private project (on my Windows PC), I want to recognize when the active window changes. So I implemented a little class setting a hook to the WinEvent *"EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND"*. The callback should be triggered when the foreground window changes. (As specified by MS) 
In general it works as expected when I click through open windows.
But if I minimize and maximize applications, the event is always **invoked twice** when I **minimize** the window and there is **no invocation** when I **maximize** it. So finally I just get informed that the window was active after it became inactive again.

**The sequence could look like the following example:**

*// Click on Win1* 

Window changed to Win1 
*// Click on Win2* 

Window changed to Win2 
*// Click on Win1* 

Window changed to Win1 
*// Minimizing Win1 in task bar* 

Window changed to Win1 
Window changed to Win2 
*// Maximizing Win1 in task bar* 

*// --> here I'd expected that I get an invocation, so I could react on the event*
*// Minimizing Win1 in task bar* 

Window changed to Win1 // --> late invocation
Window changed to Win2

**Could somebody explain this?**

---

My (essential) source code:
*(All User32-Methods are standardly from user32.dll and constants are defined as specified in MSDN)*

```
internal class WinEventListener
{
    private readonly IntPtr focusChangedWinHook;

    public WinEventListener()
    {
        User32.WinEventDelegate callback = WinEventProc;

        focusChangedWinHook = User32.SetWinEventHook(
            User32.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
            User32.EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            callback,
            0,
            0,
            User32.WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT
        );
    }

    ~WinEventListener()
    {
        User32.UnhookWinEvent(focusChangedWinHook);
    }

    void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    {
        // Doing my stuff after invocation
    }
}
```